# What were the original two results for 'died in a blogging accident'?

Tags: comics, xkcd

XKCD 369, "[Dangers](https://xkcd.com/369/)", mentions two results for 'died in a blogging accident':

[image: comic that features a bar graph showing the number of results for various Google search queries. Each search query is a variation of "died in a _____ accident"; the phrase "died in a blogging accident" is indicated to have return two search results]

But XKCD has messed up the Internet. Now there are a *lot* more results for 'died in a blogging accident' - [250k of them](https://www.google.com/search?q=died+in+a+blogging+accident).

I tried a search using Google's fancy tools, to exclude results that contained 'xkcd' and searching before the comic came out, searching for the exact term "died in a blogging accident".

It... didn't work so well; [no results were found](https://www.google.co.il/search?tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1970%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F30%2F2007&q=%22died+in+a+blogging+accident%22+-xkcd&oq=%22died+in+a+blogging+accident%22+-xkcd&gs_l=serp.3...8814.13235.0.19215.2.2.0.0.0.0.199.344.0j2.2.0....0...1.1.64.serp..0.0.0.gCCtga6RTsI). Without searching for the exact term, though, results in a bunch of irrelevant results.

So... what was Randall referring to here? What were his two results? Or did he just make the number up on the spot?

Comment: [Explain XKCD](http://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/369:_Dangers) failed me :( Time to e-mail Randall Munroe.

Comment: Email's at press@xkcd.com ;)

Comment: Wild guess: two times someone misspelled "logging accident".

Comment: I think this question is off-topic and am perfectly happy to cast the fifth close vote. The image is a picture of a graph. The fact that the graph occurs in a xkdc cartoon is irrelevant. The question asks for the source of one of the data points of said graph. I fail to see any argument as to how such a question would be on-topic on a site about literature. It's not a literary analysis question, it's not a question that you can ask about a story, etc. I've been a proponent of a broad scope, but we have to draw the line somewhere.

Comment: [Meta discussion](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/765/17) about this question and its on/off-topicness.

Comment: @Hamlet "irrelevant" - why? Would a graph occurring in another comic also be irrelevant?

Comment: @Gallifreyan I don't think Hamlet means XKCD specifically out of all comics. My reading is that, for example, this wouldn't be on-topic if it came up in a TED presentation's powerpoint slide or on talk show radio, and the fact it came up in XKCD (even taking that as a form of literature) doesn't suddenly make it on topic either.

Comment: @Gallifreyan A comment (more recent than yours) on explainxkcd links to two posts on a "steel guitar forum". Did you ever get an answer from Mr. Munroe?

Answer (score 9):

### Probably some MySpace blog page(s) which are no longer available.

This comic was published on 11 January 2008. Unfortunately the [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/%2A/http://www.google.com/search?q=died+in+a+blogging+accident) doesn't seem to list results of Google searches. I went hunting around the internet and found a couple of leads:

- according to [this forum post](https://slashdot.org/story/08/01/12/1312258/xkcd-inadvertently-causes-googlebomb), on 12 January 2008:

  > I think I found the original 2 results of the search, when the number of results was still down at 12. Both results pointed to this blog: http://blog.myspace.com/index.cfm?fuseaction=blog.view&friendID=59755147&blogID=106406778 [myspace.com]

  Unfortunately, that link is now dead, which may be why your advanced search (linked in the question) yielded no results.
- according to comments on [this blog](http://mrcopilot.blogspot.co.uk/2008/01/died-in-blogging-accident.html),on 17 January 2008:

  > The original 2 posts were about death by blogging, but didn't list anyone having died.
  >
  > MySpace deaths can probably be considered death by blogging.
  >
  > There's also a list of possible ways to die via blogging accident [here](http://journal.petajinnathandersen.com/).

  I'm not entirely sure how serious this is, and the link at the end is also dead, but it does mention MySpace - *again*. Too much for a coincidence?

Comment: Archive.org [does *not* have the MySpace URL you included in your answer.](https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://blog.myspace.com/index.cfm?fuseaction=blog.view&friendID=59755147&blogID=106406778)

Comment: @Shokhet Already checked that :-) I guess I should have mentioned it ...

Comment: It's a good research tool for dead links. Thought I'd save the next guy some trouble...